# Choosing multiple items in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array,

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

I don't know how long the array is, and I want to select everything after 3. How do i do that?

Comment: You can do like `arr.slice(arr.indexOf(3)+1)`

Comment: @Redu I'd even extend this as `arr.slice(arr.indexOf(3)+1 || arr.length)` to return an empty Array if `arr` doesn't contain a 3. Although it's not explicitely requested.

Comment: I have to vote this down, "does not show any research effort".

Comment: He didn't say after "a" 3 so it would make more sense that they're asking about the indexed slot the "3" is in.

Comment: @Thomas a very reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your example, the "3" is located in the slot for index two. If you want everything after the third element (index two) the first function will do that.

If you want everything after the first 3 found, then the second function will do that.

```js
// This finds all content after index 2
Array.prototype.getEverythingAfterIndexTwo = function() {
  if (this.length < 4) { 
    return [];
  } else {
    return this.slice(3);
  }
}

// This finds the first 3 in the array and returns any content in later indices
Array.prototype.getEverythingAfterAThree = function() {

  // returns array if empty
  if (!this.length) return this;  

  // get the index of the first 3 in the array
  var threeIndex = this.indexOf(3);

  // if no 3 is found or 3 is the last element, returns empty array
  // otherwise it returns a new array with the desired content
  if (!~threeIndex || threeIndex === this.length-1) {         
      return [];
  } else {
      return this.slice(threeIndex + 1);
  }
}

var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

console.log(arr.getEverythingAfterIndexTwo());

console.log(arr.getEverythingAfterAThree());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the index of 3, and then use [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to find everything after that element:

```
// find the index of the element 3
var indexOfThree = arr.indexOf(3);

// find everything after that index
var afterThree = arr.slice(indexOfThree + 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You splice function:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var b = a.splice( 3, a.length );
alert (b); // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
alert (a); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Be sure to clarify that this modifies the original collection.

Comment: @MarcinC. in my case, the user inputs the array. so what do i do if i don't know when is 3?

Comment: 3 is the index in the array, not the value. This means that it cuts the array in half and 4th element is the first one of the second array.